# React Error from using two different types of React in create react app (findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Currently getting the weird error: findDOMNode was called on an unmounted component.

I did some research and realized that it is because our React app is using React 16, while the company common components library is using React 15. (as per https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside/issues/231)

I tried downgrading our library to match the library's and that worked, but the problem is some parts of our library are dependent on React 16. I was wondering what the best way of resolving this conflict was.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried downgrading our library to match the library's and that worked, but the problem is some parts of our library are dependent on React 16. I was wondering what the best way of resolving this conflict was.

The only solution is to fork/upgrade the company component to react 16. I know of no way, nor would it make sense, to try to run one component with react15 and another with react16.

[Here are the react docs regarding migrating from 15->16.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#upgrading) There are very few breaking changes, which should make upgrading this component fairly easy.